# How to mock a database session scoped in python - fastapi working with SQLAlchemy as ORM to create Unit Test?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, python-unittest

I don't have much experience with unit tests and mocks.

I work with Python 3.8, pandas==2.0.1, sqlalchemy==2.0.15 and fastapi==0.87.0.

My application uses SQLAlchemy as ORM to connect to a database, creating an engine. It also automatically maps all db objects with automap.

```py
# Create the map base
tables_map = automap_base()
engine = sal.create_engine(...)
```

For simplicity, I have a function which has the decorator of *context_manager*. It works with *yield*, it returns a scoped_session.
Example of the function:

```py
@contextmanager
def database_session():
    """
    Function to create a session in the db

    Returns:
        Returns a Session with the database, ready to execute queries
    """
    # Create the session
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    # Yield it
    yield db_session
    # Commit it
    db_session.commit()
    # Close it
    db_session.close()
```

This allows me to make queries like the following example:

```py
with database_session() as databs:
    df_data_retrieved = pd.DataFrame(databs.query(table.Field1, table.Field2).distinct().where().all())
```

Specifically the data in the tables are variable, this means that even if I do the unit test today, tomorrow it may change and therefore fail.

I would like to know if there is a way to make that database_session and all the result of the code:

```py
databs.query(table.Field1, table.Field2).distinct().where().all()
```

Be replaced by a variable of my choice, for example:

```py
[{"dato1": 5, "dato2": 10}, {"dato1": 15, "dato2": 20}]
```

Resulting in the following code:

```py
def test_something(): 

    # In this function, the database call will be made,
    #    which has to be substituted by the previously described values.
    #       : [{"dato1": 5, "dato2": 10}, {"dato1": 15, "dato2": 20}]
    data_to_test = function_1()
    
    unitary_test_data = [{"dato1": 5, "dato2": 10}, {"dato1": 15, "dato2": 20}]
    
    # I know that this is not the way to compare two Dataframes, but we will believe it's
    # for the sake of make the question easier
    assert data_to_test == pd.DataFrame(unitary_test_data)
```